# optimal placement of python variables

Tags: python

i have some code that has this general structure:

```
def runSolver():
    global a
    global b
    while (condition) :
        # do some stuff
        recalculateIntermediateParameters()
        # do more stuff
    return result

def recalculateIntermediateParameters():
    # read globals
    # calculate
    return recalculatedParameter

# main
if __name__="__main__":
    runSolver()
```

I'm wondering if this is the best implementation. For instance is it bad practice to have the globals declared in a function? I know in Java, a global variable is best declared outside any function definitions.

My thought was that this would be syntactically "better":

```
def runSolver():
    a = foo
    b = bar
    # do some stuff
    return result

def recalculateIntermediateParameters(a, b):
    # do some stuff
    return recalculatedParameter
```

But what if `a` and `b` are only *read* not manipulated by the function? Does that affect global placement? Further, what if `a` and `b` are lengthy lists? Does it make sense in a performance perspective to pass the values from function to function? Which paradigm offers the best compromise between "pythonic" code and performance?

Comment: I find your question being at a level too general to be answered. I don't think there's an absolute paradigm. Use of ``global`` depends on what is aimed at in each case.

Comment: By the way, my advice would be to avoid using the word **variable** in Python, for there are only objects, underlying pointers to objects, and identifiers (directly linked to pointers under the hood and indirectly assigned to object at the algorithmic and script level). **variable** is an ambiguous word that means in other languages something that is not what are identifiers and objects in Python, that are the manageable entities in Python.

Comment: To be clear, I think that the underlying pointers are variables in the pure sense of the word, that is to say "chunk of memory whose content can changed". But the underlying pointers are not accessible to a Python programmer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *only* need to state an identifier is global when you are changing it in a function. If you only reference `a` and `b` and not assign to them, you can omit the `global` statements.

Functions are globals too, for example. `recalculateIntermediateParameters` is not being assigned to, only referenced, and you didn't need to use `global recalculateIntermediateParameters` to be able to do so.

Python uses different opcodes to assign to locals versus globals. If you do:

```
def foo():
    a = 10
```

versus

```
def foo():
    global a
    a = 10
```

Python uses two *different* operations to update `a` as a local or a global.

More generally speaking, you want to avoid using globals to pass around *state*. Pass values as parameters (using primitives, or a compound structure such as a dictionary or a custom class instance) around instead. It makes your code easier to read and debug as you can trace the state through the functions instead of having to keep track of a global separately.

Comment: ah. thanks for the clarification. but that doesn't answer the more pressing question of passing versus global declaration.

Comment: @franklin: I added a short explanation on why you'd want to avoid global state in general. Was there anything else not clear at this stage?

Comment: @Martijin I actually think at this point in my study of computer science the concept of state eludes me. From what I understand about computing specifically from Turing machines is that a program's state or m.-config describes the process that currently holds the machine's "attention". I guess from my brief perusal of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)#Program_state a program's state or machine configuration can be described as the current aggregation of all the various values stored by that program's regsiter which would accurately describe the entire `state` of the machine

Comment: is that view correct? further, are you suggesting then that at this point `globals` be removed in favor of passing these values from function to function? because of @eyquem 's statement that they are actually references, i'm assuming that performance time is not noticeably affected by this paradigm?

Comment: In this context, a *changing* global variable can be seen as state. Compare that to a global that is static, constant, such as a class definition or a function.

Comment: And this is not about performance (albeit that getting and setting local names in a function *is* faster), it is about software maintainability and easy of debugging.